# How to inject fields into existing (third-party) interfaces in TypeScript definition files?

Tags: typescript

E.g. when using express, you often need to inject new fields into koa requests/responses. The most typical scene is that when you use `body-parsre`, you inject a new `req.body` field, which is not recognized in TypeScript. The definition files of `koa-body-parser` does not seem to attempt to solve this problem.

What is the correct way in TypeScript to add definitions for these fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the correct way in TypeScript to add definitions for these fields

You write the definition in the global scope as an interface and you just extend the interface

## More

e.g. checkout how to write a jquery plugin : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/jquery.html